NotImplementedError: Input with larger batch size than 1 not supported yet
I converted the keras model to the torch model, but an error occurred. The specific code and error are as follows:
from torch import nn
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader,TensorDataset
loaded_model = load_model('D:\DeepMutation++\DeepMutation++\models\imdb_lstm.h5')
import tf2onnx

# Convert the model to ONNX format
onnx_model, _ = tf2onnx.convert.from_keras(loaded_model)
import onnx
from onnx2pytorch import ConvertModel

# Convert ONNX model to PyTorch
pytorch_model = ConvertModel(onnx_model)
print(pytorch_model)
print(pytorch_model.state_dict())
torch.save(pytorch_model.state_dict(),
"D:\DeepMutation++\DeepMutation++\models\imdb_lstm.pth")
pytorch_model.load_state_dict(torch.load
("D:\DeepMutation++\DeepMutation++\models\imdb_lstm.pth"))
print(pytorch_model)
for para in pytorch_model.parameters():
    print(para)
for name,para in pytorch_model.named_parameters:
    print(name,":",para.size())
select_data = np.load(
"D:\DeepMutation++\DeepMutation++\data\imdb.npz",allow_pickle=True)
torch_tensor_x = torch.from_numpy(select_data["x_train"])
print(torch_tensor_x)
torch_tensor_y = torch.from_numpy(select_data["y_train"])
torch_tensor_y = torch_tensor_y.view(-1,1)
print(torch_tensor_y)
BATCH_SIZE =128
N_EPOCHS = 2
device = torch.device("cuda")
model = pytorch_model.to(device)

dataset = TensorDataset(torch_tensor_x, torch_tensor_y)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, num_workers=0, shuffle=True)

optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-4)
model.eval()
# Get the dataset size for printing (it is equal to N_SAMPLES)
dataset_size = len(dataloader.dataset)
# Loop over epochs
for epoch in range(N_EPOCHS):
    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}\n-------------------------------")

# Loop over batches in an epoch using DataLoader
    for id_batch, (x_batch, y_batch) in enumerate(dataloader):
        input_tensor,output_tensor = x_batch.to(device).long(),
                                     y_batch.to(device).long()
        y_batch_pred = model(input_tensor)
        y_batch_pred = y_batch_pred.argmax()
        loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(y_batch_pred, output_tensor)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/rnn-blockwise-jackknife/influence/influence_utils.py", line 83, in 
y_batch_pred = model(input_tensor)
File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1553, in _wrapped_call_impl
return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1562, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\onnx2pytorch\convert\model.py", line 164, in forward
raise NotImplementedError(
NotImplementedError: Input with larger batch size than 1 not supported yet.
When I commented out the relevant code in the model, another error was reported：
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/rnn-blockwise-jackknife/influence/influence_utils.py", line 83, in 
y_batch_pred = model(input_tensor)
File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1553, in _wrapped_call_impl
return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1562, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\onnx2pytorch\convert\model.py", line 208, in forward
outputs = op((self,), activations, *in_activations)
File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1553, in _wrapped_call_impl
return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1562, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\onnx2pytorch\operations\loop.py", line 95, in forward
while i < M and cond:
RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous。
Can anyone help me solve there problems?
